# Uninitialized Value Error in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build Encoder-Decoder which consists of down and upsampling Convolutional network with a reference to following article and its explanation:
[image: Deep Video Portrait 2018]
[image]

This is what I wrote down, but it keep returning `uninitialized value error` 
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # hyper-params 
    learning_rate = 0.0002
    epochs = 250
    batch_size = 16
    N_w = 11 #number of frames concatenated together 
    channels = 9*N_w
    drop_out = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    def conv_down(x, N, stride, count): #Conv [4x4, str_2] > Batch_Normalization > Leaky_ReLU
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_down_{}_{}".format(N, count)) as scope: #N == depth of tensor 
            with tf.variable_scope("conv_down_4x4_str{}".format(stride)) : #this's used for downsampling
                x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=4, strides=stride, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)), name=scope)
                x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x) 
                x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x) #for conv_down, implement leakyReLU
        return x

    def conv_up(x, N, drop_rate, stride, count): #Conv_transpose [4x4, str_2] > Batch_Normalizaiton > DropOut > ReLU
        with tf.variable_scope("{}".format(count)) as scope:
            x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, N, kernel_size=4, strides=stride, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)), name=scope)
            x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
            if drop_rate is not 0:
                x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
            x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x

    def conv_refine(x, N, drop_rate): #Conv [3x3, str_1] > Batch_Normalization > DropOut > ReLU
        x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
        x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
        if drop_rate is not 0:
            x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x

    def conv_upsample(x, N, drop_rate, stride, count):
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_upsamp_{}_{}".format(N,count)) :
            with tf.variable_scope("conv_up_{}".format(count)):
                x = conv_up(x, 2*N, drop_rate, stride,count)
            with tf.variable_scope("refine1"):
                x = conv_refine(x, N, drop_rate)
            with tf.variable_scope("refine2"):
                x = conv_refine(x, N, drop_rate)
        return x 

    def biLinearDown(x, N):
        return tf.image.resize_images(x, [N, N])

    def finalTanH(x):
        return tf.nn.tanh(x)

    def T(x):  
        #channel_output_structure
        down_channel_output = [64, 128, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512]
        up_channel_output= [512, 512, 512, 512, 256, 128, 64, 3]
        biLinearDown_output= [32, 64, 128] #for skip-connection 

        #down_sampling
        conv1 = conv_down(x, down_channel_output[0], 2, 1) 
        conv2 = conv_down(conv1, down_channel_output[1], 2, 2)
        conv3 = conv_down(conv2, down_channel_output[2], 2, 3)
        conv4 = conv_down(conv3, down_channel_output[3], 1, 4)
        conv5 = conv_down(conv4, down_channel_output[4], 1, 5)
        conv6 = conv_down(conv5, down_channel_output[5], 1, 6)
        conv7 = conv_down(conv6, down_channel_output[6], 1, 7)
        conv8 = conv_down(conv7, down_channel_output[7], 1, 8)

        #upsampling 
        dconv1 = conv_upsample(conv8, up_channel_output[0], drop_out[0], 1, 1)
        dconv2 = conv_upsample(dconv1, up_channel_output[1], drop_out[1], 1, 2)
        dconv3 = conv_upsample(dconv2, up_channel_output[2], drop_out[2], 1, 3)
        dconv4 = conv_upsample(dconv3, up_channel_output[3], drop_out[3], 1, 4)
        dconv5 = conv_upsample(dconv4, up_channel_output[4], drop_out[4], 1, 5)
        dconv6 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv5, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[0])], axis=3), up_channel_output[5], drop_out[5], 2, 6)
        dconv7 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv6, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[1])], axis=3), up_channel_output[6], drop_out[6], 2, 7)
        dconv8 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv7, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[2])], axis=3), up_channel_output[7], drop_out[7], 2, 8)

        #final_tanh
        T_x = finalTanH(dconv8)

        return T_x

    # input_tensor X  
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256, channels]) # batch_size x Height x Width x N_w 

    # define sheudo_input for testing
    sheudo_input = np.float32(np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=[16, 256,256, 99]))

    # initialize_    
    init_g = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_l = tf.local_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_g)
        sess.run(init_l)
        sess.run(T(x),  feed_dict={x: sheudo_input})
```

The error detail is like below:

> FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv_upsamp_3_8/conv_up_8/8/kernel
>        [[Node: conv_upsamp_3_8/conv_up_8/8/kernel/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

conv_upsamp_3_8 is the last part of the upsampling, just befor `TanH` applied.

I think the problem might be derived from the part that I had defined convupsample referecing to other two functions - `convup` and `refine` but can't sure then why at the last step it occurs error.

Any guess or hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T(x)` is constructing the graph, but this is being called after the init tensors are made. This means the init tensors have no tensors to initialize. It could be fixed by changing the last lines to something like this:

```
output_tensor = T(x)
init_g = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_g)
    sess.run(output_tensor,  feed_dict={x: sheudo_input})
```